Solidworks: I can not draw a curve
I am trying to curve the outline but I could not figure it out,Tried to watch different videos but I could not achieve the desired result, Can someone help me please?


I am not sure what tools to use to achieve the cushion shape.

Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see How to take a screenshot. Photos are harder to read because we have to look past external interferences (like reflections, smudges or Moiré patterns) and guess if we are looking at hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connections, a software level issue like driver malfunction or glitch, or actual artifacts or issues with the drawing itself.

Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See How to upload an image to a post? or GIF

Hi. Welcome to GDSE. CAD software is generally off-topic here. Sorry about that.  Can I suggest you perhaps try Engineering Stack Exchange.

If your not so fine quality CAD program screenshot shows the method you are going to use to get the right 3D form and you only wanted that someone tells the right planar outline curve, I'd say: You will not get it, it does not exist. The 3D form is much more complex than what's possible to make by extruding.
You must widen your 3D geometry definition tool range to contain also lofting, rail sweeping and boolean operations like add, subtract and intersect. That's the minimum.
The ultimate 3D modelling method is freeform sculpting. It's available for example in Blender. It's not common in CAD programs because it's based on subdivision 3D modelling, which differs radically from what's common in CAD programs. But Solidworks advertises it as an option. It probably must be purchased or rented separately - not sure, because Solidworks is out of my reach. See this:  https://www.solidworks.com/product/3d-sculptor.
